# Why can't I connecto to my wifi AP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian, wireless-access-point

I'm connecting to my machine via ssh. Trying to connect it my to my AP. The problem is that the wi fi is active but not connected to my AP.

It is Running Debian GNU/Linux 6.0

When I run the command `iwconfig mlan0 essid MY_SSID` I get the following error.

```
Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :    
   SET failed on device mlan0 ; Bad address.
```

And checking in the log, it says:

`kernel: Can not find ssid MY_SSID`

I've already edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file adding:

```
auto mlan0
iface mlan0 inet dhcp
```

What I did after that was trying to conect with a wpa_supplicand.conf file with this line:

/usr/bin/wpa_passphrase MY_SSID MY_Secret_Wifi_Password | tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf

And I've created a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file containing:

```
network={
        ssid="MY_SSID"
        #psk=MY_PASS
        psk=MY_CIPHERD_PASS17ce47de00e8ec55983b111a79ffefdabbe5a2ca645459
}
```

I test if this Works With the line:

```
wpa_supplicant -imlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -d
```

But i get errors saying that an AP cannot be found.

I turned my interface up with:

```
linux:~# /sbin/wpa_supplicant wpa_supplicant -d wext -i mlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
```

so the ifup mlan0 says that it is already up.

If I run the `iwlist scanning` command i can see my AP.

```
mlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 08:76:FF:C5:1B:20
                    ESSID:"MY_ESSID"
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality:5/5  Signal level:-25 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Extra:Beacon interval=100
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C330C0017FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3401000700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    Extra:band=bg
```

Right now I'm connected to it via Ethernet And trying to keep the wifi connection only. Another thing is that the `lspci` command doesn't return a thing.

If another file is needed, ask me to upload it. I want to establish the wireless connection.

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend on enabling `squeeze-backports` so you use a not too old kernel version. On linux 3.2 `iwconfig` and `iwlist` are deprecated. use `iw dev wlan0 scan` and `iw dev wlan0 connect`. Also, the output of `readlink /sys/class/net/mlan0/device/driver` would be nice.

Comment: @BatchyX It doesn't recognice the `iw` commands by default, right? .. I'll check the squeeze-backports ... and with the `readlink` command I get `../../../../../../../bus/sdio/drivers/wlan_sdio`  .. what does that mean? ..

Comment: `iw` is fairly recent and it's not surprising for it to not be available by default on OS that still ship Linux 2.6.38. As for the readlink command, it means your wlan driver is called `wlan_sdio`.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/network/interfaces put:

```
auto mlan0
iface mlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid MY_SSID
        wpa-psk MY_SHARED_KEY
```

then it will connect automatically when the interface comes up

Comment: Thanks. I used it and restarted the networking service, and it seems that its getting `No DHCPOFFERS received.`.. so i'll chek it out..
On log it says `kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): mlan0: link is not ready`

Comment: Are you sure your network device is mlan0?  Mine is wlan0 on one machine and wlan1 on another.  The first error message you show has wlan0.

Comment: Yes, it is mlan0, srry I wrote it bad... let me correct the question.. but it is mlan0 .. it's showed also in the `ifconfig -a` command, but it says `Link encap:Ethernet` ...

Comment: Ok, I just wondered because that's the only difference with my working configuration. Mine's wlan0 but Link encap:Ethernet too.  I also get ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready, but then it does the authentication and becomes ready.

Comment: really ? .. where do you see it ready ? .. what do you suggest? .. if we have almost the same I should be connected by now..

Comment: In the output of dmesg

Comment: Yes... I keep getting `Invalid SSID - aborting set_essid
Can not find ssid MY_SSID ` ... and then it connect to the eth0 again..

Comment: Are you sure the SSID is right?

Comment: Yes. I thought i was misspelling too.. but I've checked several times... unless it can be named by another id or something..